# Cloning hybris project to local machine

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am new in hybris. I have been given a task that to copy hybris project from server and run it on local machine.

- I simply copied whole folder ant typed **ant all** but it gave some
  errors and build failed. However it runs in server. When I start
  server it starts but localhost://9001 shows nothing. Both server and
  local pc I am using oracle db.

Can someone please give some advise how to move existing project from server to local pc and what I need to change in files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to unzip on your local installation the hybris archive corresponding to the hybris version in production.

Then you copy/paste only the `custom` directory from your prod env (custom contains the custom code only).

You might also need to copy the config folder and you might have to change some configuration but this depends on how your project was implemented.

Once you have hybris + custom code + config run `ant clean all` then run `ant initialize` to create the db. If all works, finally run `hybrisserver` to start the server.

Note that this procedure is quite standard and you probably will have to do more steps that are related to your project.

Comment: Thanks alain.janinm. Can you me a direction where to find what I heed to change in config file.

Comment: @mamur In config folder you can take the localextensions.xml file as is. Then in local.properties you have to look on each conf to see if it need to be adapt to your environment. If you have a customize directory you'll have to run the `ant customize` cmd. You may have custom tomcat config also. Please read https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8b8e13c9866910149d40b151a9196543.html and https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8b8b1a3186691014a088ff4edd0c42f6.html to kno more about configuration in hybris.